# Is there a way to scanf up to N characters including spaces and new lines, and store them as a zero-terminated string

Tags: c, input, scanf

I want to read exactly N bytes from stdin or a file multiple times, then read less than N bytes once and then read EOF. I expected this to work:

```
char s[5] = "11111";
while (scanf("%4c", s) != EOF) {
    printf("%s", s);
}
```

However, when I type `1234567890`, it prints `1234156781`. This is because with `c` type modifier it doesn't put `\0` after read chars.

Other things I tried:

- `"%4s"` reads until first whitespace
- `"%4[^\n]"` and `fgets` do read until first end of line
- `"%4[^\0]"` doesn't work (why?)
- `"%4[]"` doesn't work
- `"%4"` doesn't work

Comment: Also note that for invalid input, all functions in the `scanf` family might return something other than `EOF`. Comparing to `EOF` usually leads to infinite loops. [Read more about what the functions return.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value)

Comment: If you need to read `N` characters of any kind, including spaces, newlines and control-characters, then there's no standard function for that. You simply need to create a loop that reads character by character until you either reach `N` or get an `EOF`.

Comment: As for why `"%4[^\0]"` doesn't work, it's because the terminal, pipe or other input source doesn't null-terminate the input. Input from a `FILE*`, one from `fopen` or `stdin`, is just a stream of bytes.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use `fread()`? `scanf()` seems more appropriate when one wants "tokenising" and "conversion" facilities...

Comment: Why do you expect to encounter end-of-file on `stdin`? This will generally only occur if standard input is piped from a file, or if the user manually triggers end-of-file, for example by pressing `CTRL-D` on Linux or `CTRL-Z` on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: Timofey X, if `N == 8` and input was `"123\n456\n"`, would you want `s[N+1]` to contain `"123\n456\n"` or `"123\n"` or what?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude [because the terminal, pipe or other input source doesn't null-terminate the input.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74928408/is-there-a-way-to-scanf-up-to-n-characters-including-spaces-and-new-lines-and-s/74934773#comment132227299_74928408).  No.  `scanf("%4[^\0]", s)` is like `scanf("%4[^", s)`.  Both  are UB because the format is invalid.  The format parsing stops at the first _null character_.

Comment: For *any* question of the form "Is there a way to do <any even slightly complicated thing> with `scanf`?", the answer is either "No", or "Maybe, but it'll be three times harder, and buggier, than if you do it some more straightforward way, like with `getchar` or `fgets`."

Comment: As an elaboration of my previous comment: Your question is unclear, because you do not clearly specify when to stop reading from `stdin`. If your question is taken literally, then you want to read until end-of-file, but if `stdin` is connected to a terminal/console, then you will probably never encounter end-of-file. Therefore, the question does not make sense (unless `stdin` is not connected to a terminal/console, which you did not state).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to scanf up to N characters including spaces and new lines, and store them as a zero-terminated string

No, not with a single `scanf()` call.

The below comes close, except it does not consume the `'\n'`, nor does it assign anything (including a *null character*) to `buff[]` when the first character is `'\n'`.

```
#define N 100
char buf[N+1];
if (scan("%100[^\n]", buf) == 1) {
```

---

> "%4[^\0]" doesn't work (why?)

`scanf("%4[^\0]", s)` is like `scanf("%4[^", s)`.
Both  are UB because the format `"%4[^"` is invalid.  The format parsing stops at the first *null character*.

Perhaps something pathologic like `scanf("%4[\001-\377]", s)` will "work", yet `scanf()` is just not the right solution for this task.

---

`fgets()` readily reads 1 line, including the `'\n'`.

```
#define N 100
char buf[N+1];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  ...
```

---

@Timofey X How does `fgets()` not meet the function needs?

---

If OP wants to read past `'\n'`, then use `fread()`.

```
#define N 100
char buf[N+1];
size_t len = fread(buf, 1, N, stdin);
buf[len] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to read exactly N bytes from stdin or a file multiple times, then read less than N bytes once and then read EOF.

You will generally not encounter end-of-file on `stdin` when it is connected to a terminal/console, unless the user presses a certain OS-specific key combination, such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Microsoft Windows.

You probably want the loop to end when you encounter the end of the line (which is when you encounter the newline character).

When using `%4c` with `scanf`, it will attempt to match **exactly** 4 characters. However, you want it to match **up to** 4 characters. Also, in the title of your question, you stated that you want `scanf` to write a terminating null character.

One way of solving this is to use `"%4[^\n]"` instead of `"%4c"`, which will match 1 to 4 characters, instead of exactly 4 characters, and will write a terminating null character.

```
char s[5];
while ( scanf( "%4[^\n]", s ) == 1 ) {
    printf( "%s", s );
}
```

However, this will not read the newline character into the buffer, so that must be done separately, if you want it.

Comment: Once `scanf( "%4[^\n]", s )` encounters a `'\n'` ( and then puts it back into `stdin`, the next `scanf( "%4[^\n]", s )` always fails.  Was it your intent to only read, at most, one line?

Comment: @chux: In your comment, you wrote: `"Was it your intent to only read, at most, one line?"` -- OP did not clearly state in the question when to stop reading and also has not responded to my request for clarification. If you take the question literally, then OP wants to read until end-of-file, but if `stdin` is connected to a terminal/console, then OP will probably never encounter end-of-file, so the question does not make sense (unless `stdin` is not connected to a terminal/console, which OP did not state).